# Why create Torchwood for a Doctor Who spin-off, instead of using UNIT?

Tags: doctor-who, torchwood

In the *Doctor Who* universe, the Earth is protected by UNIT, which is a long-established organization that goes back decades of *Doctor Who* episodes.  I'm curious why when Russell T Davies (RTD) et al. chose to create the Torchwood Institute when they chose to create a spin-off.  After all, UNIT had been shown to protect Earth for an extremely long time, and has been used in modern *Doctor Who*.  So Earth is protected by them already.  But instead of making the spin-off be about UNIT, they made a new organization.  This put the show *Torchwood* into an awkward position where UNIT shows up to assist on some threats, but doesn't show up for others.  There's no explanation given in-universe for this.  Has RTD or have any of the other *Doctor Who* or *Torchwood* show-runners explained this in interviews?

Comment: Part of the reason could be that they already did a bunch of direct-to-DVD films about UNIT: [Auton Trilogy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auton_trilogy)

Comment: Given the [history of copyright disputes involving Doctor Who characters](http://news.bbc.co.uk/1/hi/entertainment/4469761.stm), I wonder whether it was a safer/cheaper bet to create a new institution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Davies has repeatedly said that he wants to move *Torchwood* farther and farther from *Doctor Who*.  It's a much grittier, darker, and pessimistic series than *Doctor Who* and he has said that the two will continue to diverge over time.

In one [recent interview](http://io9.com/5751735/russell-t-davies-may-be-ready-to-quit-torchwood-after-this-year), it mentions, "He also says that Torchwood is intended to be the opposite of Doctor Who, where you know the main characters won't be killed off. He hints that life is not going to get any easier (or less deadly) for the few characters who remain alive. Better get Rhys and PC Andy some bulletproof vests!"  He has also stated elsewhere that regular characters would get killed off and replaced so there wasn't always a consistent and continuing cast throughout the entire show.

Since creating Torchwood and then creating a series about it is a writer's decision, you're not going to find an in-universe explanation for it.

Also, if they had used UNIT, then the choice would have been to either stop using UNIT in *Doctor Who* or to force the two to maintain a consistent continuity.

Comment: Also Torchwood was the code name for the the new Doctor Who, and is an anagram for Doctor Who.

Comment: _"Since creating Torchwood and then creating a series about it is a writer's decision, you're not going to find an in-universe explanation for it."_ While this is correct, there should actually be an in-universe explanation about why did they in-universe create Torchwood since they already had UNIT, and how does it happen that some threats are detected by one and not by the other.

Comment: From an in-universe point of view, Torchwood has existed since 1879 whereas UNIT was founded in the 1970s. Also, Torchwood 3 is based in Cardiff to specifically deal with the Rift; UNIT is a more general organisation.

Comment: Also UNIT being an United Nations organization would have to follow all rules and treaties that apply to the same, whereas Torchwood isn't beholden to anyone's rules or laws, and can exist to protect the United Kingdom's sole interests.

Comment: _"Doctor Who, where you know the main characters won't be killed off"_ Yeah except the companions every two or so years. And, um, literally the main character every three or so years. WTG RTD

Comment: _"Since creating Torchwood and then creating a series about it is a writer's decision, you're not going to find an in-universe explanation for it."_ In this case, true, but in general there's nothing stopping the writer from _creating_ an in-universe explanation for it. IMO a good writer does. Otherwise you could look at _every_ event in a TV show and say "meh, there's no reason that happened except I wanted it to happen and I'm the writer".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: There are many in-universe explanations that are necessary, but when it comes do, "Let's do a series about this instead of about that," there's really no in-universe explanation that can say, "We find Torchwood more interesting for a series."  In this case, the showrunner has stated in multiple interviews his reasoning behind the show and there's no need for anything in-universe and almost anything given in-universe would be tongue-in-cheek and impossible to do without breaking the fourth wall or have an extreme awkwardness.

Comment: @Tango: Oh, I dunno. The CIA exists alongside the US Marines. MI6 exists alongside the SAS. The Obsidian Order existed alongside the Central Command. The Tal'Shiar existed alongside the Romulan Imperial Navy. There's plenty of precedent! It just needed a one-liner and you're done. :)

Comment: You're going way off into the land of non sequitur with all the comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Torchwood was controlled and operated by England for England to protect England from unknowns and exploit aliens. Peaceful aliens show up? Kill them take there stuff!

UNIT controlled by the United Nations. Peaceful aliens show up, keep guns on them make friends, protect the world but not steal there aliens' stuff. Stuff that is safe that they do get share with the world.

Warlike alien? Blow it up.

Basically UNIT tries to be good and Doctor works with them as a sort of adviser on all things alien and unofficial ambassador/mediator.

Torchwood are blackhats and are as likely to setup a alien alliance to sell Earth's children for technology (they did once) as they are to do anything good, Jack was trying to change them. But they're scum that will do anything to get the job done and know it and do not care who or what they hurt as long as it helps England remain a world power. The Doctor would like to see them stamped out of existence. As such there a darker show a different show, than Doctor Who. Where UNIT would be just anther Doctor Who.

Comment: Peaceful my bum. Unit does some dreadful things in torchwood, not least coordinating the mass kidnapping of children

Comment: What's the point with all these capital letters and missing spaces?

Comment: @Lohoris - Happy now?

Comment: Not "England"; the UK. The fact that the entire series was set in Wales and had a predominantly Welsh cast ought to be a clue, no?